# Oracle Date format on where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, date-formatting

I have to run the report with start time between 00.00 AM and 05.00 AM , but the start time field is varchar field and its has "20211110200336"

I am trying with

WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(starttime,' YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS')BETWEEN '000000' AND '050000'

but i am getting error as "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
01840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format"
*Cause:    "

Can anyone help me how to use it

Comment: why save dates as varchar2 it costs always time to convert

Answer (score 2):

You make the decision to store a `DATE` column as a `VARCHAR2` format (which is not recomended).

Why? You can't use the provided functionality of the `DATE` data type and you must use your own implementation.

To get the *time* part (i.e. `HH24MISS`)  from your column use a `substr`

```
select substr('20211110200336',9,6) hh from dual;

HH    
------
200336
```

So the predicate would be

```
WHERE substr(starttime,9,6) BETWEEN '000000' AND '050000'
```

You **may** transform the column to the `DATE` type in the first place

```
to_date('20211110200336','yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

but you should ask yourself, **why did you not this choice in the DB design (??!)**...

Anyway to get the time part - use `to_char`

```
select to_char(to_date('20211110200336','yyyymmddhh24miss'),'HH24MISS') hh from dual;

HH    
------
200336
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all as strings:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR(starttime, 9) BETWEEN '000000' AND '050000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring, so that oracle will convert it and treat as numbers

```
create table mytime(tm varchar2(14))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytime VALUES ('20211110200336')
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO mytime VALUES ('20211110040336')
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT tm  FROM mytime WHERE substr(tm,-6) BETWEEN 0 AND 50000
```

| TM |
| --- |
| 20211110040336 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4J0z1ofb)

Of course you can make also a cast if you want to use stings for the hours minutes and seconds

```
create table mytime(tm varchar2(14))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytime VALUES ('20211110200336')
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO mytime VALUES ('20211110040336')
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT tm  FROM mytime WHERE substr(tm,-6) BETWEEN CAST('000000' as INTEGER) AND CAST('050000' as INTEGER)
```

| TM |
| --- |
| 20211110040336 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3NlzQ8Rp)